# Iterate through visual objects

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I am having a problem in Visual Studio 2013. I have like 72 picture boxes. And I have a variable named  **code** which takes a random number like 13. Now I want to change pictureBox**13**'s background color. But I don't want to make a long switch case for it. I just want something like a

```
for(int i=0;i<73;i++)
    pictureBox + code.BackColor = Color.Brown;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this a WinForm app? Or WPF or ?

Comment: WinForm, sorry. Omited to mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No loop needed (at least no loop written by you) but a single line could return the required box

```
string name = "pictureBox" + randomNumber.ToString();
PictureBox p = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name)
p.BackColor = yourColor;
```

Comment: Thank you! This works but if i have a picturebox in a User Control should I make it like string name = "usercontrol1.pictureBox" + randomNumber.ToString(); ?

Comment: Do you have 73 user controls containing 73 picture box? Or just one usercontrol with 73 picture boxes?

Comment: Just one user control containing 72 picture boxes

Comment: Then this code is better if executed inside the UserControl class, not from the form class. In the code above the _this.Controls_ refers to the controls collection of the object in which the code exists. Better have a public method inside the usercontrol called _SetBackgroundToPicture(int randomNumber, Color ColorToSet);_ and move the code above inside this new method. Your form then doesn't know how the usercontrol works but only that it needs to pass the number and the color to set